# response Data is nil

Tags: json, swift, nsdata

I am getting response data `nil`.

```
func fetchSinglePageData() {
    var response: NSData?
    var errors: NSError?
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

        response = NSData(contentsOfFile:"url...?project_id=(self.projectID)&project_page=Request", options: NSDataReadingOptions(0), error: &errors)

        print("LatestURL Single page:(response)")

        if response == nil {
            var alertview = UIAlertView(title: "Network Error", message: "Data not received due to network connection.Try again...", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
            alertview.show()
        }
        else{
            let jsonDict: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response!, options: nil, error: &errors) as NSDictionary
            print("JSON Response Single page:(jsonDict)")
            var statuses = [NSObject : AnyObject]()
            self.lblstartTime?.text = jsonDict["start_time"] as? String
            self.lblcurrentStage?.text = jsonDict["current_stage"] as? String
            self.lblcompletionTime?.text = jsonDict["completion_time"] as? String
            self.lblManager?.text = jsonDict["manager"] as? String
        }
    })
}
```

`project_id` is string which is recevied from presvious page which is correctly working.

Comment: Use URLSession to get data from the server.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func singlePageData(){

    var errors: NSError?

    let urlString = "xyz.com"
    print("URL RESPONSE  \(urlString)")

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString), cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 50)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil{
            //handel error
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            var alertview = UIAlertView(title: "Network Error", message: "Data not received due to network connection.Try again...", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
            alertview.show()
            return
        }

        if let responseData = data{

              var jsonDict: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &errors) as NSDictionary!

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

            println("Json dict value  \(jsonDict)")
            self.lblprojectName?.text = jsonDict["name"] as? String
            println("lblprojectName:  \(self.lblprojectName?.text)")
            self.lblstartTime?.text = jsonDict["start_time"] as? String
             println("lblstartTime :  \(self.lblstartTime?.text)")
            self.lblcurrentStage?.text = jsonDict["current_stage"] as? String
             println("lblcurrentStage :  \(self.lblcurrentStage?.text)")
            self.lblcompletionTime?.text = jsonDict["completion_time"] as? String
             println("lblcompletionTime :  \(self.lblcompletionTime?.text)")
            self.lblManager?.text = jsonDict["manager"] as? String

            })

            }
        }
    task.resume()

}
```

This is my answer as per Jitendra Solanki answer i have made changes to code and it is now working in Swift 1.2

Answer (score 1):

**In swift 3**

```
 //make a url request

 let urlString = "your_url"
 let urlRequest = URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: urlString)!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 50)

  //create a session
  let session = URLSession.shared

  let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
        if error != nil{
            //handle error
            return
        }else{
            if let responseData = data{
             let  jsonDict  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: [])as? [String:Any]
             //handle your response here

            }
        }
    }
  task.resume()
```

**In swift 2.2**

```
    let urlString = "your_url"

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 50)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil{
            //handel error
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if let responseData = data{

            do{
                if  let jsonDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: [])as? [String:Any]{

                    //you have data in json dict

                }

            }catch{
                print("error in parsing response")
                return
            }


        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: @DilipTiwari, I edited the answer to work in swift 2.2, the approach is same for all version, just the name of api methods are changed in swift3. I think there should not be too much changes to work in swift 1.2, you can use the code of swift 2.2 .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143153/discussion-between-jitendra-solanki-and-dilip-tiwari).

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look, maybe \ missing:

```
NSData(contentsOfFile:"url...?project_id=\(self.projectID)&project_page=Request"
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
response   = NSData(contentsOfFile:"url...?project_id=(self.projectID)&project_page=Request", options: NSDataReadingOptions(0), error: &errors)
```

you have `project_id=(self.projectID)`, to use interpolation you should instead have `project_id=\(self.projectID)`

I would suggest that you separate the code to generate your full URL, then print the URL to the console and ensure that it is what you would expect.

Then you can visit the url yourself and check to see what the server returns, then once you know you have the correct URL and response you can then work to deserialise the response

**EDIT:** updated with URLSession (Swift 3 version)

```
let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
var dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?
let projectID = 12
let url = URL(string: "http://phpyouth.com/clients/halfpricedgrannyflats/app/app_response.php?project_id=\(projectID)&project_page=Request")

dataTask = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url!) {
    data, response, error in

    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    } else if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
            if let responseData = data {
                if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject] {
                    print(json)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dataTask?.resume()
```

Comment: that url contains self.projectID instead of the actual project ID. you need to use `\(self.projectID)` to pass in the value into the string

Comment: so whats the new URL with projectID in? are you getting an error? you would be best using NSURLSession

Comment: I can see you are using an older version of xcode and swift. I have provided an example of how you can do it but its in Swift 3. I use xcode 8. if you plan to push this app to store you will need to update, I believe apple have stopped supporting iOS9 and below now

Comment: how come you removed the accepted answer? did this not help?