# blank(nil) entry inserting in database with alamofire request in swift 4. Please solve it

Tags: php, ios, swift, api, alamofire

1. This is my swift code for registration page.

   ```
   let headers : HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]
   let postString : Parameters = ["name": "com", "email": "raj123@v", "mobile": "123", "password": "123"]
   let signUpUrl = "myURL/api_register.php"

   Alamofire.request(signUpUrl, method: .post, parameters: postString, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON {
       response in
       switch response.result {
       case .success:
           print(response)
       case .failure(let eror):
           print(eror)
       }
   ```
2. this is my php api code :

   ```
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   $return_arr = array();  
   $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST["name"]);
   $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST["email"]);
   $mobile=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST["mobile"]);
   $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST["password"]);

   $result=mysqli_query($link,"insert into users(name,email,mob,password) values('$username','$email','$mobile','$password')");    
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result))
   {
   $row_array['status']=true;
   array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
   }
   else 
   {
   $row_array['status']=false;
   array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
   }
   echo json_encode($return_arr);
   mysqli_close($link);
   ```
3. Nil entry is inserting into a database with alamofire. where is the actual problem, I test all but can't get.
4. if I don't use Alamofire and This code is not working also:

   ```
   let signUpUrl = URL(string: "myURL/api_register.php")
   var request = URLRequest(url: signUpUrl!)
   request.httpMethod = "POST"
   request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
   request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


   let postString : Parameters = ["name": "com", "email": "raj123@v", "mobile": "123", "password": "123"]
   print("\(postString)")
   do {
       request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postString, options: .prettyPrinted)
       //print(request.description)
   } catch let error {
       print(error.localizedDescription)
       displayMessage(userMessage: "Something went wrong")
       return
   }
   ```

Comment: just change JSONEncoding to URLEncoding

Comment: thanks, you save my day...it's working

Comment: Anytime : ) haha

Comment: I change the code. what is the solution if I can't use alamofire and using basic method of request and same problem facing

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tb1EHigjIco just watch this tutorial and learn

Comment: there is no solution in this video... regarding mine code problem

Comment: waiting for reply

Comment: show  what you are getting in console

Comment: nothing , I print the it and its display (nil)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49321953/alamofire-and-objectmapper-adding-data-to-tableview/49322591#49322591 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718675/response-data-is-nil..you can see these answers

Comment: Actually there is no problem with getting data rather I'm facing problem to save data into database. blank entry going every time on save button click .

Comment: if you want to save data into database then use userdefaults

Comment: I'm talking about server database

Comment: do you use postman ?\

Comment: yes, api working correctly

Comment: I don't know what code you write but if the api is working correctly then the problem is in your code follow this answer step by step check all the outlets and action you made https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49124560/not-working-registering-user-in-api-programatically-in-swift-3-4/49124918#49124918 and clean up your project

Answer (score 0):

Regarding second approach you can use something like this

```
let newUrl = NSURL(string:"https://.......")

let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: newUrl! as URL, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 60.0)

urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

let body = String(format:"name=%@&email=%@","picko","werr@yahoo").data(
    using: String.Encoding.utf8,allowLossyConversion: false)


urlRequest.httpBody = body

let queue = OperationQueue()

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest as URLRequest, queue: queue)
{

    (response: URLResponse?,data: Data?, error: Error?) in



    /* Now we may have access to the data, but check if an error came back first or not */
    if error == nil
    {

        do {

            let responseDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]

            print("responseDict:\(responseDict)")



        } catch let caught as NSError
        {
            print("Error in json \(caught)")
        }



    }
    else if data?.count == 0 && error == nil
    {
        print("Nothing was downloaded")
    }
    else if error != nil
    {
        print("Error happened = \(String(describing: error))")
    }


}
```